# Изменение цвета кнопки и формы авторизации

Tags: html, css

1. Обе кнопки связаны с формой, если я выберу instagram, в post запросе будет указано, что данные получены о instagram.
   Хочу знать как это всё сделать.

   ```css
       body {
     background: #e9e9e9;
     color: #666666;
     font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   }

   /* Pen Title */
   .pen-title {
     padding: 50px 0;
     text-align: center;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
   }
   .pen-title h1 {

     margin: 0 0 20px;
     font-size: 48px;
     font-weight: 300;
   }
   .pen-title span {
     font-size: 12px;
   }
   .pen-title span .fa {
     color: #33b5e5;
   }
   .pen-title span a {
     color: #33b5e5;
     font-weight: 600;
     text-decoration: none;
   }

   /* Form Module */
   .form-module {
     position: relative;
     background: #ffffff;
     max-width: 320px;
     width: 100%;
     border-top: 5px solid #33b5e5;
     box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .form-module .toggle {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: -0;
     right: -0;
     background: #33b5e5;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     margin: -5px 0 0;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
   }
   .form-module .toggle .tooltip {
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     right: -65px;
     display: block;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     width: auto;
     padding: 5px;
     font-size: 10px;
     line-height: 1;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   .form-module .toggle .tooltip:before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     left: -5px;
     display: block;
     border-top: 5px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
     border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   }
   .form-module .form {
     display: none;
     padding: 40px;
   }
   .form-module .form:nth-child(2) {
     display: block;
   }
   .form-module h2 {
     margin: 0 0 10px;
     color: #33b5e5;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1;
   }
   .logo {
     float: right;
     margin-top: -50px;
   }
   .form-module input {
     outline: none;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
     margin: 0 0 20px;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-wieght: 400;
     -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
     transition: 0.3s ease;
   }
   .form-module input:focus {
     border: 1px solid #33b5e5;
     color: #333333;
   }
   .login-btn {
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #33b5e5;
     width: 100%;
     border: 0;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     color: #ffffff;
     -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
     transition: 0.3s ease;
   }

   .login-btn1 {
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #33b5e5;
     width: 50%;
     border: 0;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 3px;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     color: #ffffff;
     -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
     transition: 0.3s ease;
   }

   }
   #switcher:checked ~ .login-btn2 {
     background: #f00;
   }

   .login-btn2 {
     position: absolute;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
     bottom: 65%;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-left: 3px;
     background: #33b5e5;
     border: 0;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     color: #ffffff;
     -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
     transition: 0.3s ease;
   }

   #btn1, #btn2  {
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   .login-btn:hover {
     background: #178ab4;
   }
   .form-module .cta {
     background: #f2f2f2;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 15px 40px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: #666666;
     font-size: 12px;
     text-align: center;
   }
   .form-module .cta a {
     color: #333333;
     text-decoration: none;
   }

   /* The Modal (background) */
   .modal {
       display: none; /* Hidden by default */
       position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
       z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
       padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%; /* Full width */
       height: 100%; /* Full height */
       overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
       background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
   }

   /* Modal Content */
   .modal-content {
       position: relative;
       background-color: #fefefe;
       margin: auto;
       padding: 0;
       border: 1px solid #888;
       width: 80%;
       box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
       -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
       animation-name: animatetop;
       animation-duration: 0.4s
   }

   /* Add Animation */
   @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
       from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
       to {top:0; opacity:1}
   }

   @keyframes animatetop {
       from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
       to {top:0; opacity:1}
   }

   /* The Close Button */
   .close {
       color: white;
       float: right;
       font-size: 28px;
       font-weight: bold;
   }

   .close:hover,
   .close:focus {
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
   }

   .modal-header {
       padding: 2px 16px;
       background-color: #90C3D4;
       color: white;
   }

   .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

   .modal-body p {padding-top: 4px;}


   .modal-footer {
       padding: 2px 16px;
       background-color: #5cb85c;
       color: white;
   ```

   ```html
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <title>Free-Wifi</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/reset.css">
       <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='/static/css/roboto.css'>
   <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='/static/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">    
     </head>
     <body> 
   <!-- Form Mixin-->
   <!-- Input Mixin-->
   <!-- Button Mixin-->
   <!-- Pen Title-->
   <div class="pen-title">
     <h1>Добро пожаловать в зону бесплатного Wi-fi</h1><span>Для получения доступа к интернету, авторизируйтесь.</span>
   </div>
   <!-- Form Module-->
   <div class="module form-module">
     <div class="form">
     </div>
     <div class="form">
       <h2 align="center">Войти с помощью</h2>
       <!-- <img src="/static/logos/facebook-logo.png" width="25%" class="logo"></img> -->
       <form name="theform" class="theform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
         <button  type="button" class="login-btn1" name="wfphshr-vk ">VK</button>
         <button type="button" class="login-btn2" name="wfphshr-vk ">INSTAGRAM</button>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="wfphshr-email"/>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="wfphshr-password"/>
         <button class="login-btn">Вход</button>
       </form> 
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- The Modal -->
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">

       <script src='/static/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
       <script src="/static/js/index.js"></script> 
   <script>
   // Get the modal
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

   // Get the button that opens the modal
   var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");

   // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
   btn.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "block";
   }

   // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   span.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "none";
   }

   // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
           modal.style.display = "none";
       }
   }
   </script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: С таким подходом вам дорога на фриланс биржу. Что вы сделали и с чем столкнулись в процессе реализации?

Comment: Исправил вопрос.

Comment: Вместо кнопок обернуть их(VK и Instagram) в `label` и добавить `input[type="radio"]`

Comment: Извините, но не совсем понял.